# SwiftUI: List with visual separation at fixed position and drag & drop reordering

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, swiftui-list

I have got a SwiftUI list that contains a number of elements, then a visual separation, and then more elements.

The idea is that I've got a fixed number of elements that are shown more prominently elsewhere, and the separation makes it clearer which elements are that:

[image: A list with containing the elements p0, p1, p2, a separator, and then the elements p3, p4]

I want to re-order this list via drag & drop, with the constraint that the separation should remain at the same position. i.e. if I drag items from one side of the separation to the other, the separation should move so that there is the same number of fixed elements above it:

For example: If I drag p1 from 2nd place to the bottom, the separation should move between p3 and p4.

[image: A list with containing the elements p0, p2, p3, a separator, and then the elements p4, p1]

Right now I have got an ObservableObject that has a list of items. These items contain  both the elements as well as the separator. Upon move I modify the list of items, and move the separator accordingly.

This works if I publish changes to the list of items later than the move:

```
class DemoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum ID: Hashable {
        case element(Index)
        case separation
    }
    struct Item: Identifiable {
        let id: ID
        var moveDisabled: {
            self.id == .separation
        }
    }
    @Published
    var items: [Item] // filled elsewhere
    let prominentProducts = 3

    func didMove(from fromOffsets: IndexSet, to toOffset: Int) {
        var items = self.items
        items.move(fromOffsets: fromOffsets, toOffset: toOffset)
        if let offset = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == .separation }), offset != self. prominentProducts - 1 {
            items.move(fromOffsets: [offset], toOffset: self. prominentProducts)
        }

        // If I update self.items earlier, then the changes don't show up in the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.items = items
        }

    }

}

struct DemoView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel: DemoViewModel

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.viewModel.items) { item in
                self.row(for: item) // create the view matching the item
                    .moveDisabled(item.moveDisabled)
            }.onMove(perform: self.viewModel.didMove)
        }
    }
}
```

This is okay for a demo, but the delay makes it rather jarring. Is there a way to show those changes in the list immediately - ideally with the separation moving during the drag-operation?